# Thought-sending in Tibetan Buddhism and other traditions

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

In [this speech](https://youtu.be/mh8cAlNGQxI), actor [Richard Gere](https://www.hellomagazine.com/profiles/richard-gere/), in the capacity of an award presenter, made a speech at the Oscar's of 1993, asking all viewers to send out their thoughts to the Chinese government leaders and the Chinese people, to persuade them to end the Chinese occupation of Tibet and let Tibetans return to their previous independent and autonomous state.

Richard Gere made hand gestures while speaking (at time [1:33](https://youtu.be/mh8cAlNGQxI?t=93)), as though thoughts can be somehow broadcasted to the minds of people far away.

I take it that this has something to do with Tibetan Buddhism, and Richard Gere is a well known follower of the Gelugpa school of Tibetan Buddhism. Apparently, he was banned from becoming an Oscar presenter in future Oscar's, due to this speech.

How does this thought-sending work in Tibetan Buddhism? If more people send out their thoughts, is the effect stronger?

Does it have a name?

Does it also appear in other Buddhist traditions? For e.g. like sending out metta or sending out merit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can think is the "Satya Kriya" in Theravada Buddhism.
You contemplate on your virtues and extend that power for good cause such as a person to relieve from her suffering.

Anguli Mala Sutta:
"In that case, Angulimala, go to that woman and on arrival say to her, 'Sister, since I was born I do not recall intentionally killing a living being. Through this truth may there be wellbeing for you, wellbeing for your fetus.'"

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.086.than.html